# is there a way to highlight cells if *multiple* columns match exactly?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to do conditional formatting if *multiple* columns are duplicates.

I know I can find duplicates in *one* column by doing conditional formatting with something like this:

=countif($A:A,$A1)>1

But how do I do the equivalent of this?

=countif($A:A&E:E,$A1&E1)>1

In other words, I only want the cells highlighted if the *combination* of A & E are duplicates.

As an example, if A is "First name" and E is "Last name", I only want the cells highlighted if the *combination* of First name and Last name are duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A2=$A$2:A)*($E2=$E$2:E))>1
```

[image]